# Uniform Continuity implies boundedness in sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

We want to show that, letting $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ that's uniformly convergent, then there exists $M>0$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $|f_n(x)|\leq M$. I've seen some proofs of this here but I'm a bit confused on my own solution, which does not use the fact that continuous functions that uniformly converge must converge to a continuous function since it hasn't been introduced in my text at that point.

My proof attempt:

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ that's uniformly convergent to some continuous function $f(x)$ and let $\epsilon=1$. Then, we know that, by Cauchy property of uniform convergence, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n\geq N$, 
$$\big||f_n(x)|-|f_N(x)|\big|\leq |f_n(x)-f_N(x)|<1$$ (where the first part being reverse triangle inequality). Then $\forall n\geq N$, we have $$-1<|f_n(x)|-|f_N(x)|<1$$ and hence $$|f_n(x)|<1+|f_N(x)|$$
 Further, by the fact that $[0,1]$ is compact, $f_N$ is continuous (since the sequence of $f_n$ is continuous), and Extreme Value Theorem, $|f_N(x)|$ is bounded. Same logic applies for other $f_n(x)$ which are continuous and thus bounded on $[0,1]$. We then let:
$$|f_N(x)|=M_N$$
and for each $i<N$, let $M_i$ be such that:
$$|f_i(x)|\leq M_i\ (\forall x\in[0,1])$$
Taking $M=\max\{M_1,\ldots, M_{N-1}, M_N+1\}$, we have $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Was simply wondering if this argument is valid as it doesn't take some $f$ where the $f_n$ are converge uniformly towards. Thanks!

Comment: It seems a bit of overkill for me. Actually, it is pretty straightforward. Note that the uniformly limit of a continuous on a compact set is a continuous function on compact set, and a continuous function on compact set achieves its maximum.

Comment: In the first sentence in the question you left out the continuity of the limit function. Also, in the title you meant to say "uniform convergence".

Comment: @zhw sorry, yes I stand corrected

Comment: @Bach thanks, I was just trying an alternative method because the text I was self-learning from haven't introduced the notion of uniform limit of a continuous function is continuous at that point, so I was simply trying to see the method they wanted me to solve it with